# Range based for loop iteration on std::map need for explanation

Tags: c++, range-based-loop

The following code is running properly

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector> using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> m;
    m[0] = "hello";
    m[4] = "!";
    m[2] = "world";
    for (std::pair<int, std::string> i : m)
    {
        cout << i.second << endl;
    }
    return 0; }
```

However, if I replace the for loop by

```
for (std::pair<int, std::string>& i : m)
{
    cout << i.second << endl;
}
```

is not working. I get `'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::pair<const int,std::string>' to 'std::pair<int,std::string> &'`
However,

```
for (auto& i : m)
{
    cout << i.second << endl;
}
```

is working, and also If I do the following

```
for (float& i : v)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

I don't run into this problem. Why is that?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of SO related question for this.

Comment: C++ compilers have a well-earned reputation for emitting completely confusing and head-scratching error messages. This isn't the case here. The error message tells you, literally, what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key in map cannot be changed, so if you take key-value pair by reference key must be `const`.

In your example `int` variable is a key, if you take `pair` by reference, you could modify that key, which cannot be done with map.

Take a look at `map::value type`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map.